# Input simulator C# WPF Keeps throwing me errors when trying to use it

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

So I just recently transferred over from `WinForms` to `WPF` and I've got a grasp knowledge of it now and I tried using the `sendkey` class but as you already know thats not possible in WPF, so I did some research and googled for a while and I stumbled upon the `inputsimulator`.

https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/

And this code should work just fine with WPF as far as I know, I've added the reference and I've added the namespace

```
public void PressTheSpacebar()
{
  InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.SPACE);
}
```

but it keeps throwing me these 2 errors

> The type 'InputSimulator' exists in both 'InputSimulator,
>    Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and
>    'WindowsInput, Version=1.0.4.0, Culture=neutral,
>    PublicKeyToken=9b287f7dc5073cad'
>    and
>    'VirtualKeyCode' is an ambiguous reference between
>    'WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode' and 'WindowsInput.VirtualKeyCode'

A more visual reference would be this

Here is a picture of the errors:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an ambiguous reference. That means the compiler is not sure from where the method should be called. `InputSimulator` exists in both namespaces. So the compiler cannot compile properly.

To fix the issue, you need to remove any one of the namespaces. 
Probably remove `System.Windows.Input`.

**EDIT :** 
I have checked your code. Just these namespaces are required. Remove all other namespaces and build your code. It should work fine.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Net.Sockets;
```

Comment: That got rid of one of the errors im still left  with

The type 'InputSimulator' exists in both 'InputSimulator, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'WindowsInput, Version=1.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9b287f7dc5073cad'

Comment: That was what I was saying. You should remove either of the one namespaces `InputSimulator, Version=0.1.0.0` or `WindowsInput, Version=1.0.4.01` and check.

Comment: Then I get these two errors


The name 'InputSimulator' does not exist in the current context 

and

The name 'VirtualKeyCode' does not exist in the current context

Comment: https://github.com/silentwolfdev/RandomSpeechTesting/blob/master/SourceCode there you go, and thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: Thats weird, It still give me these errors 
http://i.imgur.com/mHznMiG.png

Comment: I also added the reference dll, could that be the issue?

Comment: Okay so that seemed to be the issue, i had the reference dll to the windows.input and I deleted that one and added the using WindowsInput; namespace!

Comment: Yes. `Windows.Input` is the one that is required. Hope your issue is resolved.

Comment: Hey this might sound weird and might even be against stacks rules not sure to be honest, but is there any place I can get in contact with you if I ever stumble on to any other issue? Im not one to spam so no worries on that front.

Comment: You can post your question here with proper tags added and there will be many people like me ready to help you, not just for gaining reputation alone, but also for self learning purpose. :)